# Can Gradle fail the build if the jar is too big?

Tags: gradle, aws-lambda, jar

What is a good way for gradle to warn the developer that the code/dependency change they’re making makes the built jar too big?

We’re making updates to a repo that builds a jar that’s deployed in an AWS Lambda function. We are limited to 50MB for the executable. We’d ideally like the devs to get this feedback much before our CI/CD tries to upload to a lambda function and fails.

Comment: the solution proposed in the answer is not Gradle generic feature ( there is no such feature in Gradle framework, to limit artifact sizes)) but it seems to do the job. what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You could define and use a custom task to implement the file size check, and create a dependency between this task and the task that produces the Jar.

Assuming you are using Sprinboot, you could create a [finalizer task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:finalizer_tasks) that will be executed just after the `bootJar` task and make the build fail when jar size exceeds a certain limit.

Simple implementation as example:

```
task jarSizeChecker() {
    def maxSize = 15_000_000  // jar size limit in bytes
    group "verification"
    description "Checks that the produced jar size does not exceed the defined limit"
    doLast {
        println " checking jar size"
        def jarFileSize = bootJar.archiveFile.get().getAsFile().length()
        println " fileSize is ${jarFileSize}"
        if (jarFileSize > maxSize) {
            throw new GradleException("Jar size exceed the defined limit")
        }

    }
}

bootJar.finalizedBy(jarSizeChecker)
```

Result:

```
$ ./gradlew bootJar

[...]
> Task :bootJar

> Task :jarSizeChecker FAILED
 checking jar size
 fileSize is 17333895
7 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 2 from cache

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\dev\workspaces\...\build.gradle' 

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':jarSizeChecker'.
> Jar size exceed the defined limit
```